# facebook connect in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I connect with facebook and then register in my site or connect with twitter. When i try connect to facebook login show this error:

```
Invalid Argument
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
```

I believe that the cause are the session because i don´t log out of facebook connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your application URL in your application settings on facebook.

This is via www.facebook.com/developers
Select your app, Edit settings, change the website URL.

If you are developing on localhost, change it to http://localhost:3000 or whatever your server is running on.

Comment: Thanks But I don´t believe that this was the problem because in config of facebook app I use localhost. I can connect to facebook but when i logout and more later i try connect again, The facebook popup show this error.